# Динамическое создание полей для ввода массива

Tags: android

Как в android можно создать динамический массив, для последующего заполнения? К примеру вводится размерность массива, возьмем 5, значит массив будет 5х5 и на экране выводится сетка, на подобии GridView и пользователь вводит туда данные. В итоге получается некий двумерный массив.
Сделал пока через GridView, выводить - выводит, но не могу понять можно ли вводить в него значения?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

UPD:Что бы было понятее)
Нужно на подобии такого

Comment: Можно. Вешайте слушатель нажатий и в нём в ячейку массива записывайте значение. В чём у вас конкретно проблема - не очень понятно)

Comment: 1."В чём у вас конкретно проблема" - проблема собственно в том, что я не пойму как сделать "динамическое создание полей для ввода массива" и какие компоненты для этого лучше использовать=) 2."Вешайте слушатель нажатий" - как это можно реализовать для этой задачи?

Comment: @Xom9ik почитайте вот этот урок: http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/50-urok-17-sozdanie-view-komponent-v-rabochem-prilozhenii.html потом подумайте какой элемент у вас есть ваша матрица, и сами поймете легко.

Answer (score 0):

```
Ваш_Класс Тип_Массива [][] = new Ваш_Класс [размер массива][2];
```

Comment: А как к этому прикрутить графический интерфейс для ввода?